# Typo3 disable drag and drop in page tree

Tags: drag-and-drop, typo3-10.x, disable

Working with typo3 v 10.4, I have the requirement of some back-end user groups not to be allowed to move pages around. I was able to hide the arrow-actions shown in the page list view using the RecordListHookInterface. But drag and drop in the page tree still allows moving pages. Is there any TypoScript setting I can use to disable drag 'n' drop functionality of the page tree?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no TypoScript configuration for this. But this can be done extending the "TreeController" from core with the "XClass" method:

```
<?php
namespace My\Namespace\XClass;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\Page\TreeController;

class XPageTreeController extends TreeController {
    protected function isDragMoveAllowed(): bool {
        if (!parent::isDragMoveAllowed()) {
            return false;
        }
        $beUser = $this->getBackendUser();
        return $beUser->isAdmin() || $beUser->isMemberOfGroup(123)
                || $beUser->isMemberOfGroup(234);
    }
}
```

XClasses must be registered in the ext_localconf.php like so:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\Page\TreeController::class] = [
   'className' => My\Namespace\XClass\XPageTreeController::class
];
```

Note that extending core classes has some disadvantages. For example, when switching to a newer Typo3 version, functionality might silently fail.